# How to create a new encrypted LUKS-partition in GParted?

Tags: partition, disk, luks, gparted, disk-encryption

I want to create a new encrypted LUKS-partition in GParted.

I've searched the UI and the help, but the only thing I can find is [how to open and close an *existing* LUKS partition](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-open-encrypted-partition) and how to [to copy and paste an existing one](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-copy-and-paste-partition).

However, I can find no way to create a new one. I can create a new partition e.g. for btrfs, but it is never encrypted.

So it seems for that only task of creating a new partition I have to resort to other tools like *GNOME Disks* (GNOME Disk Utility), which easily allows this when creating a new partition, or fallback to the commandline, which I'd like to avoid.
Or is there any way to create a new encrypted partition?

#### Broader use case

Actually, i want to do what is described in the GParted help: Copy an encrypted partition and „maintaining an encrypted” partition on a new disk. However, to do so (i.e. to not decrypt the data while copying), I have to paste it „into an existing open LUKS encrypted partition”, i.e. I need to have an encrypted partition first.

So, finally, **is there any way to create a *new* encrypted partition in GParted?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

GParted doesn't support creating of encrypted partitions, you'll need to use either GNOME Disks or [blivet-gui](https://github.com/storaged-project/blivet-gui) (shameless plug for my project) or you can just use `cryptsetup` directly if you are ok with using command line tools.

See [GParted Features](https://gparted.org/features.php) page for details about supported features, LUKS is listed as not supported in the *Create* column.

Comment: One other option, that I use, is [KDE Partition Manager](https://apps.kde.org/partitionmanager/) (`partitionmanager` package) . It does have LUKS encryption and plays nicely with mounting via `cryptsetup luksOpen`/`cryptsetup luksClose` commands. Once mounted with that you can see the drive on Gnome Nautilus or whatever your file manager is.